# Qt c++ does not call the move_slot for all objects. Why?

Tags: c++, qt

```
int forIterator = 0;
Scenes::Scenes(QWidget * parent): QObject ()
{
    setScene(scene);

    for(int i = 0; i < Dot::number_of_dotz; i++)
    {
        QTimer *timer_move = new QTimer();
        QObject::connect(timer_move,SIGNAL(timeout()),dotz[i],SLOT(move_slot()));
        timer_move->start(10);
    }
```

The Dot::number_of_dots gets updated(+1) in the move_slot() because there is a new dot created but yet the move_slot of the new dot is never called. 
Why is this (not) happening?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the implementation of `move_slot`.  Do you remember to call `QObject::connect(...)` on the newly created dot?

Comment: I did not remember to call QObject::connect(...). Thank you! it is working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are supposed to create a new `Dot` in `move_slot()`. `Scenes::Scenes(QWidget * parent)` constructor is being called when Dot::number_of_dotz static member has a value more than 0 and probably you already created some dot instances in it. So, the `Scene` constructor is called once and it would not be called again.

It's obvious that you are doing this because you want to start the expansion of dotz after creation of the `Scenes` class.

My solution is to check the `sender()` type in `move_slot()` and if it's a QTimer, you can create the new `QTimer` in the `move_slot()` itself.

I recommend you to set a parent for your `QTimer` to prevent memory leaks.

```
void Dot::move_slots(){

    // your code 

    QTimer *caller_object = qobject_cast<QTimer*>(sender());
    // caller_object will be nullptr if this slot is not being called
    // by an object other than a QTimer
    if(caller_object){   
        QTimer *timer_move = new QTimer(this);
        QObject::connect(timer_move,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move_slot()));
        timer_move->start(10);
    }
}
```

I hope that I was correct with my assumption about what you wanted to achieve. Leave a comment if it's not the case.

Comment: Your assumption was correct but  I have managed to get things working in a different manner. The problem was i was creating new dot objects but i was not connecting them to the signal using QObject::connect. thank you!